# C++ 2011 : good syntax to initialize an array in a constructor?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, initialization

Here I have an example class :

```
template<typename T, unsigned int SIZE> class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass();
        ~MyClass();

    protected:
        T _data[SIZE];
};

template<typename T, unsigned int SIZE> MyClass<T, SIZE>::MyClass() : // _data() OR _data({}) OR _data{} OR...
{
    ;
}
```

What is the correct C++ 2011 syntax to initialize the entire array to 0 in the default constructor ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unified initializer syntax works well:

```
MyClass() : _data{} {}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the second {} ?

Comment: @Vincent that's just the empty constructor.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand this new syntax of C++ 2011. What is the difference between : MyClass() : _data{} and MyClass() : _data{} {} ?

Comment: @Vincent: The difference is that one's legal and one isn't.  The grammar doesn't allow naming a member without also giving it a parenthesized or braced initializer.  And of course the constructor needs a body.

Comment: Ho, ok. That is the "equivalent" of MyClass() : _data{} {std::cout<<"This is my constructor"<<std::endl;} ?

Comment: One last question : this syntax works with GCC but not with Intel ICPC. Do you think that is just a question of time for Intel to accept this syntax ?

Comment: @Vincent: Yeah, the answer uses a C++11 feature, so it's not available everywhere yet.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this in C++03 without using something like `std::fill`?

Comment: @mfontanini: Yes there is (value initialize a class type that contains the array), but this question specifically wanted C++11 syntax.